# How to find object with biggest attribute value in ArrayList (using different classes)

Tags: java, class, object, arraylist, max

Java beginner here. I'm supposed to find the best result a participant has in an event (and later compare this result to others to find the winner etc).

I made classes for an event (with list of event results) , participant (with list of participant's total results), and result (with event obj, participant obj and result (double)) + a program class for the commands.

So far I have written a method that returns a participant's best result in an event as a double, but I need to return the entire result object instead. Not sure which class should be responsible for this (?) but I put this method in the event class for now.

```
public double getBestResultDouble(Participant p) {
        double best = 0;

        if (hasResult(p)) {
            for (Result r : eventResults) {
                
                if (p.equals(r.getParticipant())) {

                    double res = r.getResult();

                    if (res > best) {
                        best = res;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return best;
    }
```

Comment: Change the method signature to `Result`  instead of double and then return the winning object. To store that object you can create a instance of an object in your method.

Comment: Java 8: `return Collections.max(eventResults, Comparator.comparingDouble(Result::getResult));`

Comment: 4castle You could write that as an answer, if you were prepared to supply an explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply save the corresponding (best) result as another local variable and return that at the end:

```
public Result getBestResultDouble(Participant p) {
    double best = 0;
    Result bestResult = null;

    if (hasResult(p)) {
        for (Result r : eventResults) {

            if (p.equals(r.getParticipant())) {

                double res = r.getResult();

                if (res > best) {
                    best = res;
                    bestResult = r;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return bestResult;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to think a little more in terms of OOP (Object-Oriented Programming).

A `Participant` can participate in multiple `Event`'s. Everytime a `Participant` participates in an `Event`, there is a `Result` that gets generated for that particular `Participant` and gets a corresponding score.

Now that I have the basic structure of how I want to layout my classes, so we can define specific behavior of how we want each class to go about.

```
public class Participant
{

    private List<Event> events;
    private String name;

    public Participant( String name )
    {
        this.name = name;
        events = new ArrayList<Event>();
    }

    //... other methods

    public void participate( Event event )
    {
        double score;

        //... get the score

        events.add( event );
        event.recordResult( this, score );
    }
}
```

So now the `Participant` can participate in certain `Event`'s that you define.

Now looking at what I did in that participate method, we need to have a way to store `Result`'s inside of an `Event`.

```
public class Event
{
   private List<Result> results;

   public Event()
   {
      results = new ArrayList<Result>();
   }

   // ...

   public void scoreResult( Participant participant, double score )
   {
       //if a participant cannot participate multiple times in an event, probably need a check to see if 
       //the participant is already in the list, otherwise update the score isntead of adding a new Result

       results.add( new Result( participant, score ) ); 
   }
}
```

So now each `Event` that you define has a way to score a `Result` for a particular `Participant`.

I'll just do the basic outline for a `Result` class

```
public class Result
{

   private Participant participant;
   private double score;

   public Result( Participant participant, double score )
   {
      this.participant = participant;
      this.score = score;
   }


   // ... getters and setters
}
```

This could be a basic outline for your Objects. Now you can define a method in `Participant` to get the best `Result` of all `Event`'s he has participated in. Something like:

```
public Result getBestResult()
{
   Result bestResult = null;
   for( Event event : events )
   {
      if( bestResult == null )
         bestResult = event.getResult();
      if( bestResult.getScore() < event.getResult().getScore() )
         bestResult = event.getResult();
   }

   //if the participant hasn't participated in any event, then this will return a null result.

   return bestResult;
}
```

I hope that this makes sense and will help you think about things in a more OO way. This way you can define other methods for `Event` such as how to get the `Participant` with the highest `Result`.

Of course this is just one way to layout the classes, and I highly encourage you to try to think ahead of time how you want your objects to interact with each other before coding. Think about relationships between objects. I know you are just a beginner, so this might be a little advanced, but if you are serious about learning how to code efficiently, this is definitely something to look into.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, the most common way is to create an instance of `Comparator<Result>`, which compares instances of `Result`. You delegate the comparison to the Comparator instead of comparing yourself.

You can then use standard Java methods to do your sorting.

Standard:

```
  List<Result> = ....
  Comparator<Result> cmp = ....;
  list.sort(cmp);
  Result max = list.get(0);
```

With Streams

```
  List<Result> = ....
  Comparator<Result> cmp = ....;
  Result max = list.stream().max(cmp);
```

Double is already Comparable, so you can code your Comparator like:

```
Comparator<Result> cmp = new Comparator() {
    public int compare(Result r1, Result r2)
    {
        return r1.getResult().compareTo(r2.getResult());
    }      
}
```